# My ColdFusion Administrator is suddenly not working. What does this error mean?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-administrator

Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Application server is busy. Either there are too many concurrent requests or the server still is starting up.

Comment: *Might* be better on Server Fault.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this question more belongs on ServerFault.

This error message typically means that the web server (IIS, Apache, etc) is having trouble communicating with the App Server (ColdFusion). This can be the case if CF is mid-restart, or if it is crashing during start.

You need to check log files for clues as to what might be going on. Start with:

```
{cf-install}/logs/server.log
{cf-install}/logs/cfserver.log
{cf-install}/runtime/logs/coldfusion-event.log
```

It would also be helpful if you specified what version of ColdFusion you're running (8? 9? 5?), and how you've got it installed (standalone, multi-instance, WAR, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this error, but my guess would be that the Administrator needs access to a locked resource.  I would try restarting CF services, and maybe the whole server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Either there are too many concurrent requests or the server still is starting up.
```

Usually, I see this messsage shortly after a restart. Are you sure, the server didn't restart?

Comment: Yep, all coldfusion services are up and running.  I read on a link somewhere else it might be java related?  Or i need to update jrun or something?  UGGGH.  Who knows, it just started happening a few days ago.  The website works fine, but I can't get to CF Admin...which really sucks.

Answer (score 0):

This happend with me few times, when I restarted CF11 applications services, it shows error and keeps status as "Starting..."
When machine is reboot, it automatically turns on and works. Until then, it still shows either no services available / too many concurrent request.